# React native: WebView Auto heigh bugged on Android - javascript injection is not executing

Tags: android, ios, webview, react-native, javascript-injection

I really need to make a WebView both on Android and iOS which is going to have auto heigh for a static html. I researched and I found out that the WebView does not have that feature. Therefore I tried to implement some native libraries and again they worked for iOS but not for Android. Furthermore, I found some topics how to inject javascript into the html and to get the value for height and to set it dynamically for the WebView afterwards. However, those scripts are working on iOS but not on Android.

I tried these solutions, but they are not working for Android, even  though I enabled javascript for Android WebView.Personally, I think that the injected javascript is not executed on Android even though I configured the WebView like this:

```
    <WebView                            
        html={html}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript="document.body.scrollHeight;"
        scrollEnabled={false}
        onNavigationStateChange={this._updateWebViewHeight}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
        style={{height: this.state.webViewHeight}}
    />
```

Here is a screenshot, I printed out the event object from onNavigationStateChange, one is from Android and the other is from iOS, and they do not have the same fields :( Please help. Thank you

[Screenshot for Android emulator and iOS emulator with printed event object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPWu5.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [react-native-html-webview](https://github.com/almost/react-native-html-webview). It's been working well for me and easy to use.

   `var HTMLWebView = require('react-native-html-webview');
   <HTMLWebView
       html = {htmlContent}
       makeSafe = {true}
       autoHeight = {true}/>`
2. Check out this gist: [WebViewResizing.js](https://gist.github.com/dbasedow/ed6e099823cb8d5ab30e)

Comment: Thank you mate, but it is only for iOS and the problem is on Android

Comment: Did option2 work on android? Please share if you've found a solution.